# Nginx log questions: how to record the access to a specific URL?

Tags: logging, nginx

Currently I want to put the access to a specific URL into a signle Log file,

the access log is always like below:

POST /forum.php?mod=misc&action=rate&ratesubmit=yes&infloat=yes&inajax=1

How can I put these access into a single log file?